# Python display same bin width for different bin sizes

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have this code

```
bins = [0,1,10,20,30,40,50,75,100]
plt.figure(figsize=(15,15))
plt.hist(df.v1, bins = bins)
```

My problem is that the bin widths as they appear in the figure are proportional to their range in `bins`. However, I want all bins to come out having the same width.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure how you'll make sense of the result, but you can use `numpy.histogram` to calculate the height of your bars, then plot those directly against an arbitrary x-scale.

```
x = np.random.normal(loc=50, scale=200, size=(2000,))
bins = [0,1,10,20,30,40,50,75,100]
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(211)
ax.hist(x, bins=bins, edgecolor='k')
ax = fig.add_subplot(212)
h,e = np.histogram(x, bins=bins)
ax.bar(range(len(bins)-1),h, width=1, edgecolor='k')
```

[image]