# matplotlib histogram with equal bars width

Tags: matplotlib

I use a histogram to display the distribution. Everything works fine if the spacing of the bins is uniform. But if the interval is different, then the bar width is appropriate (as expected). Is there a way to set the width of the bar independent of the size of the bins ?

[This is what i have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62aOs.png)

[This what i trying to draw](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYOE0.png)

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

my_bins = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 120]
my_data = [5, 5, 6, 8, 9, 15, 25, 27, 33, 45, 46, 48, 49, 111, 113]

fig1 = plt.figure()

ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(121)
ax1.set_xticks(my_bins)
ax1.hist(my_data, my_bins, histtype='bar', rwidth=0.9,)
fig1.show()
```

Comment: This is not really a histogram. Calculate the histogram first, then plot a bar plot with the bars centered at half the bin width away from their left bin edge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot mark your question as a duplicate, but I think [my answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43900135/1356000) might be what you are looking for?

---

I'm not sure how you'll make sense of the result, but you can use `numpy.histogram` to calculate the height of your bars, then plot those directly against an arbitrary x-scale.

```
x = np.random.normal(loc=50, scale=200, size=(2000,))
bins = [0,1,10,20,30,40,50,75,100]
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(211)
ax.hist(x, bins=bins, edgecolor='k')
ax = fig.add_subplot(212)
h,e = np.histogram(x, bins=bins)
ax.bar(range(len(bins)-1),h, width=1, edgecolor='k')
```

[image]

---

**EDIT** Here's with the adjustment to the x-tick labels so that the correspondence is easier to see.

```
my_bins = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 120]
my_data = [5, 5, 6, 8, 9, 15, 25, 27, 33, 45, 46, 48, 49, 111, 113]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(211)
ax.hist(my_data, bins=my_bins, edgecolor='k')
ax = fig.add_subplot(212)
h,e = np.histogram(my_data, bins=my_bins)
ax.bar(range(len(my_bins)-1),h, width=1, edgecolor='k')
ax.set_xticks(range(len(my_bins)-1))
ax.set_xticklabels(my_bins[:-1])
```

[image]

Comment: The result looks like I wanted. But how to make x-axis signatures the same as bins ranges (10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 120 instead of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)

Comment: As I've said, the bars are plotted against an arbitrary scale, so it's just a matter of re-labeling the ticks to match your bins. I've updated my answer.