# What is the name of this type of graph?

Tags: python, graph

I want to reproduce this graph in Python, but I don't know what the name of this graph is.  Some keys features of this discrete graph are:

- presents three variable that describe the data
- two of the variables have been normalized to sum to unity.
- the third variable is ordered from smallest to greatest

I did a reverse image google search, but to no available.  Other similar questions here ask for names of other objects/features/graphs but not this particular graph.

If there is a named graph in Python, then I want to use it.  If there is not, then I will create it and give it the common/well-known??? name.

The key feature that I find attractive in this graph is

- the ability to intuitively (area of a rectangle) related two variables (% of participants and % of total emission) for each discrete data point (country)

[image]

For your curiosity, the data is carbon emissions produced by participants while they travel to/from a science conference in California, US, and is found in the supplementary materials of a recent article published in Nature 583, 356–359 (2020)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called a waterfall chart. The X-axis has variable bin sizes for indexes but their labels have been modified to only show the start of a bin as if its a continuous axis. You can use the width of each bar equal to the size of the bin on x axis. This will give you the rectangles you are looking for. I also see few line plots at specific x and y values for marking interesting parts of the graph at 26%, 61% etc.

[image]

You can use plotly to work on charts like these. Code for a sample chart -

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(go.Waterfall(
    name = "20", orientation = "v",
    measure = ["relative", "relative", "total", "relative", "relative", "total"],
    x = ["Sales", "Consulting", "Net revenue", "Purchases", "Other expenses", "Profit before tax"],
    textposition = "outside",
    text = ["+60", "+80", "", "-40", "-20", "Total"],
    y = [60, 80, 0, -40, -20, 0],
    connector = {"line":{"color":"rgb(63, 63, 63)"}},
))

fig.update_layout(
        title = "Profit and loss statement 2018",
        showlegend = True
)

fig.show()
```

For visualizations like these, I would not really recommend python in the first place. Something like this is super easy to make in excel though.

Comment: Thanks, but a waterfall chart visualizes the cumulative effect of sequentially introduced positive or negative values.  It's a 'bar chart' where all but the first and last bars are 'suspended' above the x-axis.  I'm looking for a chart that relates the values on the x-axis and the y-axis by producing a series of rectangles that are 'suspended' above the x-axis.  In other words, a waterfall chart has a fixed-width for each entry (bar/rectangle).  What I'm looking for does not.

Comment: Like i mentioned, you can set the bin width to be variable in the chart. refer to this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58183804/matplotlib-histogram-with-equal-bars-width

Comment: Thanks, I should have paid closer attention to your answer.  I'll look into it more closely.